# What are "states" when using SaltStack?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying SaltStack after using Puppet for a while, but I can't understand their use of the word "state".

My understanding is that, for example, a light switch has 2 possible states - on or off. When I write my SLS configuration I am describing [what state a server should be in](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/starting_states.html). When I ask SaltStack to provision a server I issue the command `salt '*' state.highstate`. I understand that a server can be in a `highstate` (as described in my config) or not. All good so far.

But [this page describes other states](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/layers.html). It describes `lowstate`, `highstate` and `overstate` (amongst others) as *layers*. Does this mean a server passes through several states to get to a highstate? Or all states are maintained simultaneously as layers? Or can I configure multiple possible states in my SLS and have SaltStack switch between them? Or are they just layers to SaltStack that have 'state' in the name and I'm confused?

I'm probably missing something obvious, if anyone can nudge me in the right direction I think a lot of the documentation will become clear to me!

Answer (score 8):

Here, top.sls wihch contain,

```
# cat top.sls
base:
 '*':
  - httpd_require
```

and,

```
# cat httpd_require.sls
install_httpd:
 pkg.installed:
   - name: httpd
 service.running:
   - name: httpd
   - enable: True
   - require:
     - file: install_httpd
 file.managed:
   - name: /var/www/html/index.html
   - source: salt://index1.html
   - user: root
   - group: root
   - mode: 644
   - require:
   - pkg: install_httpd
```

## High state:

We can see all the aspects of high state system while working with state files( .sls), There are three specific components.

- High data:
- SLS file:
- High State

  - Each individual State represents a piece of high data(pkg.installed:'s block), Salt will compile all relevant SLS inside the top.sls, When these files are tied together using includes, and further glued together for use inside an environment using a top.sls file, they form a High State.

    ```
    # salt 'remote_minion' state.show_highstate --out yaml
    remote_minion:
      install_httpd:
        __env__: base
        __sls__: httpd_require
        file:
        - name: /var/www/html/index.html
        - source: salt://index1.html
        - user: root
        - group: root
        - mode: 644
        - require:
         - pkg: install_httpd
        - managed
        - order: 10002
        pkg:
        - name: httpd
        - installed
        - order: 10000
        service:
        - name: httpd
        - enable: true
        - require:
          - file: install_httpd
        - running
        - order: 10001
    ```

First, an order is declared, All States that are set to be first will have their order adjusted accordingly. Salt will then add 10000 to the last defined number (which is 0 by default), and add any States that are not explicitly ordered.
Salt will also add some variables that it uses internally, to know which environment (__env__) to execute the State in, and which SLS file (__sls__) the State declaration came from, Remember that the order is still no more than a starting point; the actual High State will be executed based first on requisites, and then on order.

"In other words, "High" data refers generally to data as it is seen by the user."

## Low States:

""Low" data refers generally to data as it is ingested and used by Salt."

Once the final High State has been generated, it will be sent to the State compiler. This will reformat the State data into a format that Salt uses internally to evaluate each declaration, and feed data into each State module (which will in turn call the execution modules, as necessary). As with high data, low data can be broken into individual components:

- Low State
- Low chunks
- State module
- Execution module(s)

  ```
   # salt 'remote_minion' state.show_lowstate --out yaml
   remote_minion:
   - __env__: base
     __id__: install_httpd
     __sls__: httpd_require
     fun: installed
     name: httpd
     order: 10000
     state: pkg
   - __env__: base
     __id__: install_httpd
     __sls__: httpd_require
     enable: true
     fun: running
     name: httpd
     order: 10001
     require:
     - file: install_httpd
     state: service
   - __env__: base
     __id__: install_httpd
     __sls__: httpd_require
     fun: managed
     group: root
     mode: 644
     name: /var/www/html/index.html
     order: 10002
     require:
     - pkg: install_httpd
     source: salt://index1.html
     state: file
     user: root
  ```

Together, all this comprises a Low State. Each individual item is a Low Chunk. The first Low Chunk on this list looks like this:

```
    - __env__: base
      __id__: install_httpd
      __sls__: httpd_require
      fun: installed
      name: http
      order: 10000
      state: pkg
```

Each low chunk maps to a State module (in this case, pkg) and a function inside that State module (in this case, installed). An ID is also provided at this level (__id__). Salt will map relationships (that is, requisites) between States using a combination of State and __id__. If a name has not been declared by the user, then Salt will automatically use the __id__ as the name.Once a function inside a State module has been called, it will usually map to one or more execution modules which actually do the work.

Answer (score 1):

`salt '\*' state.highstate`

1. '*' refers to all the minions connected to the master.
2. 'state.highstate' is used to run all modules / scripts mentioned in **top.sls** defined in master
3. To invoke a specific module / script on all minions, use the following salt command where the state information is defined in **state.sls** for **apache** in the example given below.

`salt '\*' state.sls apache`

To invoke the above salt call only on a specific minion, use the below command.

`salt 'minion-name' state.sls apache`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all levels of state, but when you run :

```
salt '*' state.highstate
```

Saltstack apply the states you provide in **/srv/salt/top.sls**.

If you write nothing in it, you can't apply an highstate.

You can apply other state with this command :

```
salt '*' state.sls state.example
```

Answer (score 0):

A `highstate` is just the collection of states that is applied to your server. There is a process in the background where Salt's "state compiler" goes through several stages preparing the data in order to produce the `highstate`, but you don't really need to worry about those.

Things like the `lowstate` can help with debugging, but aren't necessary for day to day usage. The `highstate` is only applied once.